# Retrieving data from array of Json Objects Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, xcode, google-maps

So I'm trying to do a Google map based app, and trying to get data from JSON file, which I already got.

The array looks like this :

```
collection : [Marker] = [Marker(id: "13", name: "Place 13", lat: 12.2130003, lng: 12.2130003),Marker(id: "16", name: "Place 16", lat: 12.184, lng: 12.184), Marker(id: "25", name: "Place 25", lat: 12.2250004, lng: 12.2250004), Marker(id: "22", name: "Place 22", lat: 12.1780005, lng: 12.1780005)]
```

Marker is a struct that I made to parse Data from JSON, and now I'm trying to get all of the lattitude and longitude data, and made Google maps Markers from it. The thing is i can do it with method like:

```
 func getLatLng() {
    let marker1Lat = collection[0].lat
    let marker1Lng = collection[0].lng
}
```

but it just looks awful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add all markers from `collection` array then you need to simply loop through the array and add marker in map.

```
for item in collection {
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: item.lat, longitude: item.long)
    marker.title = item.name
    marker.map = self.googleMapView
}
```

Comment: So sorry mate, didn't know about that.

Comment: @Tonamini Its Ok, it happens :)